# How to configure PG text search dictionary through sql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I want to add terms to a text search dictionary without access to the file system shares/tsearch_data (specifically for google cloud SQL).

Is there a syntax to do this via SQL?

All I have found is "ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY.." which can configure how a dictionary works, but cannot be used to add or remove lines in the dictionary .rules/.syn/.dict file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design (it's hardcoded) `tsearch_data` directory is in `SHAREDIR`. If you want to change SHAREDIR you should use your own compiled version of PostgreSQL. If you are interested, you can read the documentations' [Installation from Source Code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html) section and If you still want to change tsearch_data, well PostgreSQL is opensource, you can change [Makefile](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/tsearch/Makefile) and [ts_utils.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/tsearch/ts_utils.c) and again have your own version of PostgreSQL by compiling it.

You can also use symbolic link.